# Adding prices to my select options javascript/html

Tags: javascript, html

```html
<label>
 Total
 <input value="£0.00" readonly="readonly" type="text" id="total"/>
</label>
```

Below are the html and js for my website i am building. I am trying to get the values to increase in the total for the tem selected, this will be 1 item from the radio buttons. however everytime i choose an option the total stays at £0. i am new to js and i am having trouble. any help would be appreciated!

```js
function totalIt() {
  var input = document.getElementsByName("size");
  var total = 0;
  for (var i = 0; i < input.length; i++) {
    if (input[i].checked) {
      total += parseFloat(input[i].value);
    }
  }
  document.getElementById("total").value = "£" + total.toFixed(2);
}
```

```html
Small (£3.99)<input type="radio" name="size" id="s1" value="3.99" onclick="totalIt()"/>
Medium (£4.99)<input type="radio" name="size" id="s2" value="4.99" onclick="totalIt()"/>
Large (£5.99)<input type="radio" name="size" id="s3" value="5.99" onclick="totalIt()"/>
```

Comment: There's no `#total` element in your html.

Comment: Agreed the missing `#total` is one issue, and the OP should have included it or explained why it's not in the snippet; but I don't think that's the only issue. See my answer for some options based on what you're trying to accomplish.

Comment: i forgot to include it. i have now added it into the post!

Answer (score 0):

Change this `document.getElementById("total").value = "£" + total.toFixed(2);`

to read

`document.getElementById("total").innerHTML = "£" + total.toFixed(2);`

You need to use innerHTML to print out to the screen. .value is getting the value of that element.

Answer (score -1):

Part of the issue is the missing `#total` element (presumably an `input`, given that you are trying to change its value).

But judging from the name of the function & element, I'm assuming you also want `total` to increment whenever you click one of the radio inputs. For that, you need to move your `total` variable to outside the function, which will create a [closure](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Closures) (i.e. your `total` variable will retain its value in between calls to `totalIt()`). Note that I added a `break` since there's no need to keep checking the other radio boxes once you found your checked one.

```js
// Note this is outside the function
var total = 0;

function totalIt() {
  var input = document.getElementsByName("size");
  for (var i = 0; i < input.length; i++) {
    if (input[i].checked) {
      total += parseFloat(input[i].value);
      // exit loop once checked radio is found
      break;
    }
  }
  document.getElementById("total").value = "£" + total.toFixed(2);
}
```

```html
Small (£3.99)<input type="radio" name="size" id="s1" value="3.99" onclick="totalIt()"/>
Medium (£4.99)<input type="radio" name="size" id="s2" value="4.99" onclick="totalIt()"/>
Large (£5.99)<input type="radio" name="size" id="s3" value="5.99" onclick="totalIt()"/>

<div>
  Total <input type="text" readonly id="total" value="£0.00"/>
</div>
```

Alternatively, you can read & parse the value from your `input#total` element, in case there are reasons as to why you can't use a closure here.

```js
function totalIt() {
  var input = document.getElementsByName("size");
  var total = parseFloat(document.getElementById("total").value.slice(1));
  for (var i = 0; i < input.length; i++) {
    if (input[i].checked) {
      total += parseFloat(input[i].value);
      // exit loop once checked radio is found
      break;
    }
  }
  document.getElementById("total").value = "£" + total.toFixed(2);
}
```

```html
Small (£3.99)<input type="radio" name="size" id="s1" value="3.99" onclick="totalIt()"/>
Medium (£4.99)<input type="radio" name="size" id="s2" value="4.99" onclick="totalIt()"/>
Large (£5.99)<input type="radio" name="size" id="s3" value="5.99" onclick="totalIt()"/>

<div>
  Total <input type="text" readonly id="total" value="£0.00"/>
</div>
```

In both of the cases above, you don't actually need radio inputs or a loop, since the radios are basically acting like buttons; you can just replace them with regular buttons and call `totalIt()` (which can be greatly simplified) with an argument for the amount by which to increment.

If you are actually not interested in a running total and just want to display the total of the checked items at any given time, then you're really looking for a checkbox input, and then you don't need to worry about closures, parsing, or breaks.

```js
function totalIt() {
  var input = document.getElementsByName("size");
  var total = 0;
  for (var i = 0; i < input.length; i++) {
    if (input[i].checked) {
      total += parseFloat(input[i].value);
    }
  }
  document.getElementById("total").value = "£" + total.toFixed(2);
}
```

```html
Small (£3.99)<input type="checkbox" name="size" id="s1" value="3.99" onclick="totalIt()"/>
Medium (£4.99)<input type="checkbox" name="size" id="s2" value="4.99" onclick="totalIt()"/>
Large (£5.99)<input type="checkbox" name="size" id="s3" value="5.99" onclick="totalIt()"/>

<div>
  Total <input type="text" readonly id="total" value="£0.00"/>
</div>
```